# WSDL parsing error in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, axis

I have a WSDL which was generated using Apache Axis 1.2.1.
Now i am trying to create the stubs using JAX-WS 2.1 web service framework.

While generating the stubs, i am getting the validation errors. Due to this issues, it is unable to create the stubs.

!WSDL Validation Error Image[image]

I tried to create the stubs through many tools like MyEclipse IDE, SOAP UI Tool & Java's native wsimport.bat files.
Above all three scenarios i had failed to create the stubs due to the unsupported format.

But when i had tryied to create the stubs using SOAP UI tool with Apache Axis 1.2.1 libraries, then it was created the stubs. But those are different.

My query is, WSDL is a W3C standard format. so, any JAVA API should fallow this standard, then why this WSDL is unable to create the stubs??
and
So, I need to create the stubs using the JAX-WS 2.1 instead of Apache Axis 1.2.1.

Please suggest me the possible answer...

[Click here for WSDL](https://www.mediafire.com/?bta4v8t2bvdgbcz)

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're seeing are Web Service Interoperability (WS-I) 
compliance errors. Your WSDL document is valid. You can disable WS-I 
validation under Window->Preferences->Web Services->Profile Compliance and 
Validation. Set both WS-I AP and WS-I SSBP to Ignore compliance.

If you do want to get rid of the errors try removing the import for the 
schema for schema.

```
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

This line is unncessary as the schema types are implicitly imported and 
I've seen this cause problems with tools before.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <import namespace="http://holder.webservices.external"/>
```

This is the namespace location where your schema is defined and this is not accessible via tools while creating your stub. If you will simply put this in internet browser, you will get could not find page error.

To resolve it either save your schema locally on your computer and change the import location within wsdl accordingly or define elements within schema in wsdl itself.